# Hive on Google Cloud wants permissions on /tmp, but no way to change permissions

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-compute-engine, chmod, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run Hive on a Google Cloud, where Hadoop was installed by [click-to-deploy](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/hadoop/click-to-deploy). Hive seems to instal just fine, but when I run `hive` I get the following erroneous output:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/michael_w_sherman_gmail_com/apache-hive-0.14.0-bin/l
ib/hive-common-0.14.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!
/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/michael_w_sherman_gmail_com/apache-hive-0.14.0-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.
0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/
hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:672)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current per
missions are: rwx------
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:430)
        ... 7 more
```

My first fix was to check `hdfs-site.xml` and change the `dfs.permissions.enabled` setting, but it was already set to `false`. Next, I tried to `chmod` the permissions. But the chmod changes don't take.

> $ hadoop fs -ls
>
> 15/01/28 23:03:13 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.2.9-hadoop2
>
> Found 8 items
>   ....
>
> drwx------   - xxxx_gmail_com xxxx_gmail_com          0 2015-01-28 21:54 tmp
>
> $ hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /tmp
>
> 15/01/28 23:03:31 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.2.9-hadoop2
>
> $ hadoop fs -ls
>   15/01/28 23:09:35 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.2.9-hadoop2
>
> Found 8 items
>   ....
>
> drwx------   - xxx_gmail_com xxx_gmail_com          0 2015-01-28 21:54 tmp

Different `chmod` options, like `a+w`, fail to change the permissions. And the owner/group of the file is always equal to the ssh user (the log above is from an ssh terminal launched from Google Cloud's console, which uses your email as a username). But I have the same problem when I ssh in.

How do I either change the permissions or get Hive to not give the error?

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Hive did you install?

Comment: Also, any chance you can provide the full stack trace, *including* the "Caused by...." pieces? It's necessary to trace into the root cause out of http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hive/hive-exec/0.14.0/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/session/SessionState.java#444

Comment: @DennisHuo see edits to answer. Thank you for your help and let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the time being, the GCS connector for Hadoop doesn't support fine-grained HDFS permissions, and thus the reported 700 is "fake"; in fact, permissions are controlled via [ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol), and if using the service account with read/write access, any linux user in the authenticated GCE VM is in fact able to read/write/execute on all files inside GCS.

It appears Hive 0.14.0 freshly [introduces an unfortunate attempt](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hive/hive-exec/0.14.0/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/session/SessionState.java#527) to check for a minimum permission of 733 on the root dir, even though if it just ignored the permissions, accessibility would have worked out just fine. Unfortunately, for the moment, the "required permissions" isn't configurable in Hive's SessionState, nor is it configurable in the GCS connector for Hadoop; in a future release, we can potentially provide a config setting for the GCS connector for Hadoop to specify what permissions to report, and/or implement full fine-grained posix permissions on all directories.

In the meantime, it appears Hive 0.13.0 doesn't have the same unfortunate check, so if you're okay with the slightly older Hive version, it should work just fine.

**Important:** That said, note that the "click to deploy" solution doesn't currently officially support Pig or Hive, in part because it doesn't yet set up the more advanced "NFS consistency cache" [introduced in gcs-connector-1.3.0/bdutil-0.36.4](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gcp-hadoop-announce/ZBETJm2WENE), with automated setup of the list-consistency cache. **Without the list-consistency cache, Hive and Pig may unexpectedly lose data since they rely on "ls" to commit temporary files**.

Your best bet is actually to download the [latest bdutil-1.1.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gcp-hadoop-announce/dLDvzDMdVFw) and use that instead; it supports Pig and Hive with:

```
./bdutil -e querytools deploy
```

or equivalently:

```
./bdutil -e extensions/querytools/querytools_env.sh deploy
```

Inside that `querytools_env.sh` file, you'll find:

```
# URIs of tarballs to install.
PIG_TARBALL_URI='gs://querytools-dist/pig-0.12.0.tar.gz'
HIVE_TARBALL_URI='gs://querytools-dist/hive-0.12.0-bin.tar.gz'
```

Where you may optionally upload your own Hive version to your own bucket and modify `HIVE_TARBALL_URI` for `bdutil` to pick it up. Hive 0.14.0 still won't work, but you might have luck with Hive 0.13.0. Alternatively, if you don't care about the version too much, the default Hive 0.12.0 receives continuous testing and validation from Google's engineering teams, so you'll have a better-validated experience. You can also view bdutil's contents on GitHub if you wish, at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil

Comment: `bdutil` did the job, I was able to jump right into Hive and run jobs. Thank you!